# Ubuntu 20.04 can't access my windows network

Tags: 20.04

My Ubuntu 20.04 does not access the windows network (D-link NAS-320L Share center), the error is the following: Failed to mount the windows share: Connection termination caused by software.In previous distros everything was normal.

Comment: please, did you upgrade from Ubuntu 18 or just boot new Ubuntu sdk

Comment: Eu usei numa partição nova, outras distros baseadas no Ubuntu 20.04 tem o mesmo problema!

Comment: I used it on a new partition, other distros based on Ubuntu 20.04 have the same problem!

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution on internet.. By Tejas Lotlikar:
Same issue here.

Since version 4, both Samba Server & Samba Clients do not allow an older level of protocols negotiation. You have to enable them in smb.conf file

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf file (need root permissions)

in the [global] section, add the following line

client min protocol = NT1
Save the file and exit the editor.

You must restart the Samba Service for this change to take effect. In a terminal, enter this command:

sudo service smbd restart

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and it actually worked!

Comment: Lifesaver - bueno! Why wasn't this added to the default in 20.04? Have they lost their minds?

Comment: This isn't the default because it is a security risk. Most modern Windows servers will require NT2 or 3. So this answer is not going to work for anyone on a corporate network.

Comment: But it should be able to be enabled in a dialog for a desktop that aspired to "just work". Regardless of security risk vendors should not second guess usage.  Not being connected at all may be a security event in itself. The reality is that Ubuntu is largely a "pass through" Debian.